# Properly format json dict object with powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Please excuse my complete ineptness when it comes to using powershell. I'm not really a windows guy and I've found myself in a sticky situation. What I need to do is use a json config file named `optionsConfig.json` that contains a dict and based off whatever key I have, I assume that the elements in the list (value for that key) are environment variables on the system and I need to find their values. Here are the config contents.

```
{"test1": ["options_size", "options_connection", "options_object"],
 "test2":["options_customArgs", "options_noUDP", "options_noName"]}
```

In this example I'll say,

```
$env:options_size = 'size1'
$env:options_connection = 'conn1'
$env:options_object = 'obj1'
```

I know that I will have an environment variable on the system called `test` and value of that will be some key in the json object. Here is what I have so far.

```
# Read the JSON file into a custom object.
$configObj = Get-Content -Raw C:\TestWare\carstenSample\optionsConfig.json | 
ConvertFrom-Json

# Retrieve the environment variables whose
# names are listed in the $env:test property
# as name-value pairs.
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:testTool
```

Also, this code will convert the environment variables to Json but in a form that I do not prefer

```
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:testTool |
  Select-Object Name, Value | ConvertTo-Json
```

Here is the output

```
[
  {
    "Name": "options_connection",
    "Value": "conn1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "options_object",
    "Value": "obj1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "options_size",
    "Value": "size1"
  }
]
```

Is there a way when I can modify that Json or is their a different way to convert these env variables to json so my json object can look like this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
{
    "options_size": "size1",
    "options_connection": "conn1",
    "options_object": "obj1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to convert your example to self-test-one. Here are the results:

```
#your options
$env:options_size = 'size1'
$env:options_connection = 'conn1'
$env:options_object = 'obj1'

#your key in configuration
$env:testTool = "test1"

#your configuration (in memory to simplify)
$configObj = '{"test1": ["options_size", "options_connection", "options_object"],
 "test2":["options_customArgs", "options_noUDP", "options_noName"]}' | ConvertFrom-Json

#convert object to hashtable
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:testTool |
  % {$hash = @{}} {$hash[$_.Name]=$_.Value} {$hash} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Nicely formatted JSON is returned:

```
{
    "options_size":  "size1",
    "options_object":  "obj1",
    "options_connection":  "conn1"
}
```